# Is this a good description of time?

Tags: spacetime, time

Someone told me that "time" is us seeing 3D slices of 4D spacetime, and that an object in spacetime is a 4D object which is tenseless and contains the past present and future of that object. I don't know much about physics, so is this a good explanation?

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is a good video to watch to understand the 4D spacetime:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44ngv-8b8FM

It talks about many aspects of time involving special relativity, general relativity, thermodynamics (irreversibility), and many more. At about 22 minutes the spacetime is compared to a loaf of bread that can be cut in many different directions by observers moving at different speeds, to explain the relativity of simultaneity. With more and more research done in quantum gravity, cosmology, and high-energy physics, I believe people will have an updated view of spacetime in the future.